# Магнитометр mpu 9150 вывод данных

Tags: c, железо

Проблема заключается в выводе откалиброванных данных с магнитометра. Поворот вокруг оси Z(вперед) и X(вправо) показывает нормально, но как только поворачиваю его вокруг оси Y(вверх), поворот немного виден, но амплитуда значительно сужается сужается, т.е. как будто данные о направлении севера есть, но они смещены относительно 0,0,0. На картинке 3 видно как поворот вокруг оси Y меньшей амплитуды, чем поворот вокруг осей X и Z (круг меньшего диаметра). 
Возможно я не правильно откалибровал магнитометр? 
[image: вокруг Y] 
[image: XYZ]
Пунктир - то, что ожидается при повороте вокруг вертикальной оси.
Возможно, эти данные нужно каким-то образом нормализовать, чтобы привести к реальному вектору относительно севера, но не имею представления как это сделать.

[image: From other src]

Вот откалиброванные значения, один в один с моими, взятые в сети из другого источника. Красные, синие и зеленые точки - это те данные, которые получаются при повороте вокруг вертикальной оси. Как теперь их привести к нормальному виду, для отображения реальной ориентации?

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно, как вопрос связан с языком С. К тому же я очень туманно представляю себе принцип работы магнИтометра, но ещё из школьного курса физики помню структуру силовых линий магнитного поля вокруг Земли. И у меня есть сильное подозрение, что если ось магнИтометра ориентировать перпендикулярно направлению силовых линий (т.е. вертикально), то он должен показывать ноль.

Comment: Неправильная калибровка может иметь место, но не стоит также забывать о том, что векторы магнитной индукции не параллельны поверхности Земли. Они параллельны только на экваторе, а в северном полушарии склоняются вниз.

Comment: Да, неправильная калибровка здесь присутствует. При правильной калибровке центр этой окружности должен быть в точке (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Вопрос не связан с языком C, но тэг был указан в надежде что C близок к хардварщикам, которые в своём опыте наверняка работали с магнИтометром, простите за ошибку. Не нашел тэгов а-ля magnetometer или hardware. 
Данные на картинке не откалиброваны, да. Но откалибровав значения, вычислив амплитуду по всем осям, и нормализовав все данные в векторе, получается что вращение вокруг оси Y дает неполную амплитуду. т.е. если идеально множество данных в своей совокупности по всем осям представляют сферу, то вращая магнетометр по оси Y данные образуют окружность возле "полюса", а не вокруг центра.

Comment: Но максимум амплитуды для Y приходятся именно при вращении вокруг оси не Y

Comment: То есть у вас получается, что всё множество возможных точек, которые выдаёт магнетометр, образует эллипсоид, а не сферу? Всё равно дело в калибровке. Как вы калибровали ваш прибор? Попробуйте [эту методику калибровки](http://www.st.com/resource/en/design_tip/dm00286302.pdf). Также для грубой, но простой и быстрой калибровки можете почитать [здесь](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/314998/154202).

Comment: Данные на картинке не откалиброваны, но суть вовсе не в ней. Откалибровав значения, я получаю почти идеальную сферу. Но проблема в получении данных относительно плоскости земли, радиус разброса точек при повороте в плоскости XZ 20%, в плоскости XY, YZ - 100%. Визуальные подробности сейчас добавлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь я вас понял. Вы описывали окружность осью магнитометра с центром в воображаемой оси Земли. Когда воображаемая ось была направлена вперёд и вправо, всё было в порядке. Когда вы описывали окружность вокруг воображаемой оси, направленной вверх, проблема возникла от того, что вектор магнитной индукции не параллелен поверхности Земли. Вот что у вас получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, как я понимаю, ваша задача - вычислить азимут. В простейшем случае можно воспользоваться формулой:

```
float azimuth = atan2(z, x);
if (azimuth < 0) azimuth += 360;
```

Однако крен и тангаж вносят большие искажения в показания магнитометра. Поэтому магнитометр должен всегда работать в паре с акселерометром (либо нужно обеспечивать строго горизонтальное положение). Методику расчёта углов поворота с помощью магнитометра и акселерометра можно найти [здесь](http://www.st.com/resource/en/design_tip/dm00286303.pdf).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! теперь вопрос: чтобы не производить калибровку акселерометра, как можно достать roll & pitch из кватерниона, который получается в результате DMP ( DMP - встроенная технология Invensense Digital Motion Processing в MPU серии 6XXX и 9XXX, которая обрабатывает данные гироскопа и акселерометра, и выдаёт правильную ориентацию, кроме ориентации в плоскости земли.)?